# Show message box when the check box in the datagridview is checked

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a database like this (view on `DataGridView`):

[image]

As you can see on the image above, there are checkboxes in the `DataGridView`. I want when the checkbox is checked, the messagebox show a some text.

How can I achieve that?

What I have tried is whenever I checked the checkbox, the messagebox never appear and the first row of January 2014 column is checked when I run the program, but when I uncheck and check again, the messagebox not appearing.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
private void Amount(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable _dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;

            foreach(DataGridViewRow _row in _dt.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(_row.Cells["4"].Value) == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Checked");
                }
            }

        }
```

And I called it in:

```
dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.Amount);
```

I added the checkboxes by manually through database, here is my access database looks like:

[image]

Your answer much appreciated! Thank you!

***UPDATE:***

The code below is the code from Sir Daniloloko that I have modified, I used the `List<int>`, because the ColumnIndex that I want to check is more than 1:

```
dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.Amount);

List<int> _columnIndexes;

private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            {
                dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            }
        }

private void Amount(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            _columnIndexes = new List<int>(new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 });

            foreach (int index in _columnIndexes)
            {
                if (e.ColumnIndex == index)
                {
                    var value = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();

                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(value) == true)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Checked. \n" + "Column Number: " + e.ColumnIndex + "", "Checked");
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Not Checked. \n" + "Column Number: " + e.ColumnIndex + "", "Not Checked");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But from the code above, still the `MessageBox.Show("Not Checked");` or `MessageBox.Show("Checked");` is not showing whenever I checked or unchecked the CheckBox(es) in the `DataGridView` (On the runtime). What I want is the `MessageBox` is show whenever right after I checked or unchecked the CheckBox(es), not when I hit `Enter` or `Update` button then the `MessageBox` is shows (depending my checkbox(es) is unchecked or checked)

Thank you very much!

Sorry for confusing you guys more.

***Solved:***

I forgot to declared the `dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(this.DirtyStateChanged);` in the `Form_Load`.

Thank you very much and sorry for confusing you guys.

Regards.

Comment: How do you subscribe to check box `Checked` event?

Comment: It looks unchecked and it's probably not null.  You don't have a MessageBox for that scenario.  You aren't using _dt by the way.  You clearly need to use a DataGridView event like CellValueChanged.

Comment: Run your code after data is bound, not after the load event of grid control

Comment: You must associate an event `CheckChanged` to each CheckBox and then when you click on it you can your "MessageBox.Show("Checked");" or `MessageBox.Show("Unchecked")`; depending.

Comment: Cell[3] looks like StudentLastName.

Comment: You keep claiming this is the code you are using, but your posted code keeps drastically changing every few minutes.  Your ForEach loop should throw an exception since a DataTable.Rows collection can't use DataGridViewRow objects.

Comment: @LarsTech: Sorry for that sir LarsTech, I keep trying and trying to find out how this is happen and keep updating my question and the code to show that the previous change is already been used and failed to show what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you associate **Amount** to an event named **CellValueChanged** it will rise every time you load the GRID. Resolved!

However if you need to detect the row thats you checked after the load of the grid, you will need to use the event named CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged of dataGridView1:

EDIT: `dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(this.DirtyStateChanged); // Declared and put this on the Form_Load`

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

And your CellValueChanged event of dataGridView1 will be like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        var value = ((DataGridView) sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

***UPDATE:***
Your method will be this:

```
private void Amount(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == N)//YOUR CHECKBOX COLUM INDEX
        {
            var value = ((DataGridView) sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(value) == true)
                    MessageBox.Show("Checked");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Not Checked");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think for you... you need only to associante the Amount to the Event CellValueChanged. and it will be resolved... if not, you are taking the wrong cell value

Comment: Hi Daniloloko, I have tried your code and it is working. But it is not what I want, I have added the `MessageBox.Show("Checked");` after the `var value = ....;` and whenever I checked or unchecked the checkbox, the `MessageBox.Show("Checked");` not appearing until I click the `Update` button. Thank you though. I want it when I check the checkbox, the `MessageBox.Show("Checked");` appearing, not when I checked the checkbox and until I press the `Update` button, the MessageBox appear. Thank you though

Comment: Thats a little strange...try to put a breakpoint on the "if" of CellValueChanged... and see if something strange is occurring.

Comment: I have put the breakpoint on `if` of the `CellValueChanged` and the case still same like the one I mention on the previous comment sir, the `IsCurrentCellDirty` is true when I click the `Update` button

Comment: The problem is I didn't declared the `dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(this.DirtyStateChanged);` in the `Form_Load`.

Anyway, it works now. Thank you very much sir! I have +1 your answer and marked it.